# How to set a max-height on a table <td>

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a Dashboard page on my application which is set out in a 3 column way, I want to set a Max-height on the  so that when I select something that is relative it doesn't make it bigger. Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="dashboardcontent">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 140px; vertical-align: top">
                            <DayPilot:DayPilotNavigator ID="navigator" runat="server"
                                Width="140px"
                                Height="519px"
                                BoundDayPilotID="calender_control"
                                SelectMode="Month"
                                ShowMonths="3"
                                SkipMonths="3"
                                CellHeight="22"
                                DataStartField="start"
                                DataEndField="end"
                                VisibleRangeChangedHandling="CallBack"
                                OnVisibleRangeChanged="navigator_VisibleRangeChanged"      />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 0px;"></td>

                        <td style="vertical-align: top">
                            <DayPilot:DayPilotMonth ID="calender_control" runat="server"
                                Width="100%"
                                Height="519px"
                                OnCommand="calender_control_Command"
                                EventClickJavaScript="alert(e.text());"
                                OnEventMenuClick="calender_control_EventMenuClick"
                                ViewType="Weeks"
                                Weeks="5"
                                Theme="bsimplexcalender"
                                OnBeforeEventRender="calender_control_BeforeEventRender"
                                BubbleID="DayPilotBubble1"
                                DataStartField="start"
                                DataEndField="end"
                                DataTextField="name"
                                DataValueField="id" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 2px"></td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 140px; border: 1px solid #c6a9f2" runat="server" id="righside">

            </td>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Comment: Try  position:absolute;

Comment: The most browser-compliant way is to put a `<div>` in the `<td>` which you put all the content in, and use that to apply your styles to.